# Multiple definition of `texture' *_*

Tags: c++, opengl, текстура

Ошибка линковщика или криворукий  программист, помогите, решить проблемку

Собственно пишу на Code::Blocks'e ошибка и код программы ниже

> D:/cPlusPlus/OpenGL/OpenGL_1-2/MyTexture/OpenGL_basic.cpp:6:
> multiple definition of `texture'
> obj\Debug\main.o:/cPlusPlus/OpenGL/OpenGL_1-2/MyTexture/main.cpp:15:
> first defined here

main.cpp

```
#include "OpenGL_basic.h"

static HGLRC hRC;       // Постоянный контекст рендеринга
static HDC hDC;         // Приватный контекст устройства GDI

BOOL    keys[256];      // Массив для процедуры обработки клавиатуры

GLfloat rtri;               // Угол для пирамиды
GLfloat rquad;              // Угол для квадрата

GLvoid DrawGLScene()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);// Очистка экрана и буфера глубины
glLoadIdentity();               // Сброс просмотра
glTranslatef(-1.5f,0.0f,-6.0f);         // Сдвиг влево и вглубь экрана
glRotatef(rtri,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);         // Вращение пирамиды по оси Y
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glTranslatef(1.5f,0.0f,-7.0f);      // Сдвинуть вправо и вглубь экрана
glRotatef(rquad,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);    // Вращение куба по X, Y & Z
glBegin(GL_QUADS);          // Рисуем куб
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f);        
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);      // Право верх квадрата (Верх)
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f);    
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);      // Лево верх
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      // Лево низ
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      // Право низ
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f);      // Оранжевый
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);      // Верх право квадрата (Низ)
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);      // Верх лево
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);      // Низ лево
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);      // Низ право
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);      // Красный
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      // Верх право квадрата (Перед)
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      // Верх лево
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);      // Низ лево
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);      // Низ право
    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);      // Желтый
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);      // Верх право квадрата (Зад)
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);      // Верх лево
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);      // Низ лево
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);      // Низ право
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);      // Синий
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      // Верх право квадрата (Лево)
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);      // Верх лево
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);      // Низ лево
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);      // Низ право
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);      // Фиолетовый
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);      // Верх право квадрата (Право)
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      // Верх лево
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);      // Низ лево
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);      // Низ право
    glEnd();                // Закончили квадраты

rtri+=0.2f;     // Увеличим переменную вращения для треугольника
rquad-=0.15f;       // Уменьшим переменную вращения для квадрата
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
                HWND    hWnd,
                UINT    message,
                WPARAM  wParam,
                LPARAM  lParam)
{
    RECT    Screen;     // используется позднее для размеров окна
    GLuint  PixelFormat;
    static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),  // Размер этой структуры
        1,              // Номер версии (?)
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |// Формат для Окна
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |// Формат для OpenGL
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,// Формат для двойного буфера
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,  // Требуется RGBA формат
        16,             // Выбор 16 бит глубины цвета
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,// Игнорирование цветовых битов (?)
        0,              // нет буфера прозрачности
        0,              // Сдвиговый бит игнорируется (?)
        0,              // Нет буфера аккумуляции
        0, 0, 0, 0,     // Биты аккумуляции игнорируются (?)
        16,             // 16 битный Z-буфер (буфер глубины)
        0,              // Нет буфера траффарета
        0,              // Нет вспомогательных буферов (?)
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE, // Главный слой рисования
        0,              // Резерв (?)
        0, 0, 0         // Маски слоя игнорируются (?)
    };
    switch (message)    // Тип сообщения
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        hDC = GetDC(hWnd);  // Получить контекст устройства для окна
        PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
            // Найти ближайшее совпадение для нашего формата пикселов
        if (!PixelFormat)
        {
            MessageBox(0,"Can't Find A Suitable PixelFormat.","Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            // Это сообщение говорит, что программа должна завершится
            break;  // Предтовращение повтора кода
        }
        if(!SetPixelFormat(hDC,PixelFormat,&pfd))
        {
            MessageBox(0,"Can't Set The PixelFormat.","Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
        if(!hRC)
        {
            MessageBox(0,"Can't Create A GL Rendering Context.","Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        if(!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC))
        {
            MessageBox(0,"Can't activate GLRC.","Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &Screen);
        InitGL(Screen.right, Screen.bottom);
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        case WM_CLOSE:
        ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0);

        wglMakeCurrent(hDC,NULL);
        wglDeleteContext(hRC);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd,hDC);

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        keys[wParam] = TRUE;
        break;

        case WM_KEYUP:
        keys[wParam] = FALSE;
        break;

        case WM_SIZE:
        ReSizeGLScene(LOWORD(lParam),HIWORD(lParam));
        break;

        default:
    return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam));
    }
    return (0);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
        HINSTANCE hInstance,
        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        LPSTR lpCmdLine,
        int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG     msg;    
    WNDCLASS    wc; 
    HWND        hWnd;

    wc.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc      = (WNDPROC) WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra       = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra       = 0;
    wc.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon            = NULL;
    wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground    = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName     = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName    = "OpenGL WinClass";

    if(!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
    MessageBox(0,"Failed To Register The Window Class.","Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    return FALSE;
    }

    hWnd = CreateWindow(
    "OpenGL WinClass",
    "Jeff Molofee's GL Code Tutorial ... NeHe '99",

    WS_POPUP |
    WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,

    0, 0,           
    1366, 768,

    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);

    if(!hWnd)
    {
    MessageBox(0,"Window Creation Error.","Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;           // Режим работы

    memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(DEVMODE));  // Очистка для хранения установок
    dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);      // Размер структуры Devmode
    dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth    = 1366;         // Ширина экрана
    dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight   = 768;          // Высота экрана
    dmScreenSettings.dmFields   = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT; // Режим Пиксела
    ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN);
    // Переключение в полный экран

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    SetFocus(hWnd);

    while (1)
    {
        // Обработка всех сообщений
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
        {
            if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
            else
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }

        DrawGLScene();              // Нарисовать сцену
        SwapBuffers(hDC);           // Переключить буфер экрана
        if (keys[VK_ESCAPE]) SendMessage(hWnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);    // Если ESC - выйти
    }
}
```

OpenGL_basic.cpp

```
#include "OpenGL_basic.h"

void LoadTexture(void)
{
        // Загрузка картинки
    AUX_RGBImageRec *texture1;
    texture1 = auxDIBImageLoad("Data/kilakil1.bmp");
    // Создание текстуры
    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, texture1->sizeX, texture1->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture1->data);

};

GLvoid InitGL(GLsizei Width, GLsizei Height)    // Вызвать после создания окна GL
{
    LoadTexture();          // Загрузка текстур
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    // Разрешение наложение текстуры

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                            // Очистка экрана в черный цвет
    glClearDepth(1.0);      // Разрешить очистку буфера глубины
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);   // Тип теста глубины
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);// разрешить тест глубины
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);// разрешить плавное цветовое сглаживание
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);// Выбор матрицы проекции
    glLoadIdentity();       // Сброс матрицы проекции
    gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)Width/(GLfloat)Height,0.1f,100.0f);
                            // Вычислить соотношение геометрических размеров для окна
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);// Выбор матрицы просмотра модели
};

GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei Width, GLsizei Height)
{
    if (Height==0)      // Предотвращение деления на ноль, если окно слишком мало
        Height=1;

    glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
        // Сброс текущей области вывода и перспективных преобразований

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);// Выбор матрицы проекций
    glLoadIdentity();           // Сброс матрицы проекции

    gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)Width/(GLfloat)Height,0.1f,100.0f);
        // Вычисление соотношения геометрических размеров для окна
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // Выбор матрицы просмотра модели
};
```

OpenGL_basic.h

```
#include <windows.h>        // Заголовочный файл для Windows
#include <gl\gl.h>          // Заголовочный файл для OpenGL32 библиотеки
#include <gl\glu.h>         // Заголовочный файл для GLu32 библиотеки
#include <gl\glaux.h>       // Заголовочный файл для GLaux библиотеки

GLvoid InitGL(GLsizei Width, GLsizei Height); // Вызвать после создания окна GL

GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei Width, GLsizei Height); //Размер меняется ?! настраиваем проекцию

GLuint  texture[1]; //под текстуру место

void LoadTexture(void);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы два раза подключаете файл `OpenGL_basic.h`, следовательно, препроцессор (а он тупо заменяет директиву `#include` на содержимое файла, чье имя указано после него), создает две копии `OpenGL_basic.h` (первая подставляется вместо директивы `#include "OpenGL_basic.h"` в `main.cpp`, а вторая копия подставляется за место такой же директивы, но уже в файл `OpenGL_basic.cpp`). И переменная `texture` сначала объявляется в `main.cpp`, а потом, уже второй раз, в `OpenGL_basic.cpp`.

Поэтому все содержимое H-файла всегда помещайте внутрь вот такого защитного кода:

```
#ifndef _FILE_NAME_H
#define _FILE_NAME_H
// содержимое h файла
#endif
```

Например:

```
#ifndef _OPENGL_BASIC_H
#define _OPENGL_BASIC_H

#include <windows.h>        // Заголовочный файл для Windows
#include <gl\gl.h>          // Заголовочный файл для OpenGL32 библиотеки
#include <gl\glu.h>         // Заголовочный файл для GLu32 библиотеки
#include <gl\glaux.h>       // Заголовочный файл для GLaux библиотеки

GLvoid InitGL(GLsizei Width, GLsizei Height); // Вызвать после создания окна GL

GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei Width, GLsizei Height); //Размер меняется ?! настраиваем проекцию

GLuint  texture[1]; //под текстуру место

void LoadTexture(void);

#endif
```

Это позволит включать H-файл множество раз и не вызовет никаких проблем.